# Java number pyramid going up in 2's

Tags: java

I need to create a number pyramid that will be a sideways pyramid that goes up. Look at this picture:

[image: pic1]

However, when I mess about with either the (i++) or (j++) it will either repeat each line of the pyramid twice eg: `1 1 13 13` like in this picture:

[image: pic2]

How can I stop each line from repeating but still go up in 2's like image 1? Here is my code:

```
System.out.println("What number would you like?");
    int x = input.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Would you like 1. odd 2. even 3.both types of numbers? Please enter the NUMBER");

    int numbertype = input.nextInt();
    int y;
    //ODD
    if (numbertype == 1) {
        y = 2;

        for (int i = 1; i <= x; i++) {
            for (int j = 1; j <= i; j+=2) {
                System.out.print(j);
            }
            System.out.print("\n");
        }
        for (int p = x; p >= 1; p--) {
            for (int r = 1; r <= p; r+=2) {
                System.out.print(r);
            }
            System.out.print("\n");
        }
    }
```

Help would be much appreciated!

Comment: I highly encourage you to divide your code into smaller, simple methods. Create a method that will print `1`, `1 3` or `1 3 5` based on an argument. Then put that method into 1 or 2 `for` loops

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in a single loop. You better always try to find a simpler solution before starting to throw around with for loops.

```
int i = 1;
while (i >= 1) {
    IntStream si = IntStream.rangeClosed(1, i);
    String s = si.mapToObj(Integer::toString).collect(Collectors.joining(" "));
    System.out.println(s);
    i += y;
    if (i > x) {
        i -= 2*y;
        y = -y;
    }
}
```

Here `i` will run from 1 to `x` incrementing by `y` (I assume you wanted to use that instead of a constant). As soon as `x` is surpassed, `i` will be lowered and decremented the same amout by negating `y`. The other code is just creating an int range and joining it.